# Theme Builder All Parts shows locked

Tags: plugins

I have installed the Elementor free plugin on my WordPress site,

now when I go to Admin->Templates->Theme Builder, I see that all the SITE PARTS are locked,
see the below image,

why this happened I don't know.

someone please help me to unlock this.

[image]

Comment: you need to ask this in an Elementor community, questions about 3rd party products/themes/plugins you download are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: @James Martin,  Did you solve it?, it just happened to me too, As far as Im verifying it seems that elementor has updated itself, because now I have this button "upgrade" on the left menu, and Astra Theme is locked